# Prevent aws lambda code execute for multiple time

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, webhooks

I have a very important webhook which call my lambda function. The issue is this webhook is hitting my lambda function thrice with same data. I don't want to process thrice. I want to exit if it's already being called. I tried to store the data (paid) in dynamo db and check if it's already present but that ain't working. it's like the db is not atomic.

I call below method before executing the code.

```
def check_duplicate_webhook(user_id, order_id):
    try:
        status = dynamodb_table_payment.get_item(Key={'user_id': user_id},
                                                 ProjectionExpression='payments.#order_id.#pay_status',
                                                 ExpressionAttributeNames={
                                                     "#order_id": order_id,
                                                     '#pay_status': "status"
                                                 })
        if "Item" in status and "payments" in status['Item']:
            check = status['Item']['payments'][order_id]

            if check == 'paid':
                return True

        return False
    except Exception as e:
        log(e)
        return False
```

Updating the database

```
 dynamodb_table_payment.update_item(Key={'user_id': user_id},
                                       UpdateExpression="SET payments.#order_id.#pay_status = :pay_status, "
                                                        "payments.#order_id.#update_date = :update_date, "
                                                        "payments.#order_id.reward = :reward_amount",
                                       ExpressionAttributeNames={
                                           "#order_id": attr['order_id'],
                                           '#pay_status': "status",
                                           '#update_date': 'updated_at'
                                       },
                                       ExpressionAttributeValues={
                                           ":pay_status": 'paid',
                                           ':update_date': int(time.time()),
                                           ':reward_amount': reward_amount
                                       })
```

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB isn't atomic and if the three requests come very close together, it could happen that the read value isn't consistent. For financial transactions it is recommended to use [DynamoDB transactions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/).

May I also suggest that you use [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) and decouple the triggering from the actual execution. The webhook will trigger a function that will register the payment for execution. A different function will execute it. You will need some orchestration in the future, if for not anything else, to implement a retry logic.

Answer (score 0):

You're separating the retrieve and update, which can cause a race condition. You should be able to switch to a [put_item()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.put_item) with condition, which will only insert once (or optionally update if the criteria are met).

You could also use a FIFO SQS queue as an intermediary between the webhook and Lambda, and let it do the deduplication. But that's a more complex solution.

It also appears that you're storing all orders for a given customer in a single record in DynamoDB. This seems like a bad idea to me: first because you need more RCUs/WCUs to be able to retrieve larger records, second because you will eventually bump up against the size limit of a DynamoDB record, and third because it makes the update logic more complex. I think you would be better to manage orders separately, using a key of (`user_id, order_id`).